# Resusing select subquery/result

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, union, rdbms

I am trying to optimize the speed of a query which uses a redundant query block. I am trying to do a row-wise join in sql server 2008 using the query below.

```
Select * from 
(<complex subquery>) cq
join table1 t1 on (cq.id=t1.id)
union
Select * from  
<complex subquery> cq
join table2 t2 on (cq.id=t2.id)
```

The `<complex subquery>` is exactly the same on both the union sub query pieces except we need to join it with multiple different tables to obtain the same columnar data.

Is there any way i can either rewrite the query to make it faster without using a temporary table to cache results?

Comment: CTE's perhaps? Google for it, and see if it suites your needs.

Comment: @leppie - CTEs will not generally materialize the results without using a plan guide as described here http://explainextended.com/2009/05/28/generating-xml-in-subqueries/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a temporary table and see if that improves the execution stats?

In some circumstances the Query Optimizer will automatically add a spool to the plan that caches sub queries this is basically just a temporary table though.

Have you checked your current plan to be sure that the query is actually being evaluated more than once?

Comment: Temp table is the way to go, even though you might need to make sure you don't trash your tempdb thus slowing the rest of your DB.

Comment: The query mentioned above is used on a search box, which means at the present user load we will have this query fired anywhere between 100 to 1000 times per second...Do you think the tempDb can handle that ?

Answer (score 1):

Without a concrete example it's difficult to help, but try a WITH statement, something like:

```
WITH csq(x,y,z) AS (
  <complex subquery>
)
Select * from 
 csq
join table1 t1 on (cq.id=t1.id)
union
Select * from  
 csq
join table2 t2 on (cq.id=t2.id)
```

it sometimes speeds things up no end

Answer (score 0):

Does the nature of your query allow you to invert it?  Instead of "(join, join) union", do "(union) join"?  Like:

```
Select * from
(<complex subquery>) cq
join (
    Select * from table1 t1
    union 
    Select * from table2 t2
) ts
on cq.id=ts.id
```

I'm not really sure if double evaluation of your complex query is actually what's wrong.  But, as per your question, this would be a form of the query that would encourage SQL to only evaluate `<complex query>` once.

Comment: Unfortunately not...the results from the complex query is required in both the sql union snippets....and yes im trying to avoid multiple  evaluation of complex subquery